# How to cut html tag from very large multiline text file with content with use perl, sed or awk?

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

I want to transform this text (remove `<math>.*?</math>`) with sed, awk or perl:

```
{|
|-
| colspan="2"|
: <math>
[\underbrace{\color{Red}4,2}_{4 > 2},5,1,7] \rightarrow
[2,\underbrace{\color{OliveGreen}4,5}_{4 < 5},1,7] \rightarrow
[2,4,\underbrace{\color{Red}5,1}_{5 > 1},7] \rightarrow
[2,4,1,\underbrace{\color{OliveGreen}5,7}_{5 < 7}]
</math>
|-
|
: <math>
[\underbrace{\color{OliveGreen}2,4}_{2 < 4},1,5,{\color{Blue}7}] \rightarrow
[2,\underbrace{\color{Red}4,1}_{4 > 1},5,{\color{Blue}7}] \rightarrow
[2,1,\underbrace{\color{OliveGreen}4,5}_{4 < 5},{\color{Blue}7}]
</math>
: <math>
[\underbrace{\color{Red}2,1}_{2 > 1},4,{\color{Blue}5},{\color{Blue}7}] \rightarrow
[1,\underbrace{\color{OliveGreen}2,4}_{2 < 4},{\color{Blue}5},{\color{Blue}7}]
</math>
: <math>
[\underbrace{\color{OliveGreen}1,2}_{1 < 2},{\color{Blue}4},{\color{Blue}5},{\color{Blue}7}]
</math>
|}
```

Into such text (please forgive me if I remove too much - I should remove `<math>.*?</math>`):

```
{|
|-
| colspan="2"|
: 
|-
|
: 
: 
: 
|}
```

I read about 20 page and tested 10 scripts but without good results. The best what I do is:

```
cat dirt-math.txt | awk '/<math>/{cut=1; print;}/<\/math>/{cut=0}!cut'
```

Whatever it not works correctly since lefts `<math></math>` it is not bad but I do not know awk to improve it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all data is so nicely formatted as in your example, then your solution is very close. I modified it only slightly

in AWK:

```
sub(/<math>.*/, "") {print; cut=1}
/<\/math>/          {cut=0; next}
!cut
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion I do not know awk so you suggestion will allow to do next step which is very hard for me.

Comment: I will check it again since I make mistake somewhere :)

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's!<math>.*?</math>!!sg' dirt-math.txt
```

`-p` says we're doing a sed-like readline/printline loop, `-0777` says each "line" is actually the whole input file, and `-e` specifies the code to run (on each "line" (file)).

---

If your text files are too big to fit into memory (?!), you can try this:

```
perl -pe 's!<math>.*?</math>!!s; if ($cut) { if (s!^.*?</math>!!) { $cut = 0 } else { $_ = "" } } if (!$cut && s!<math>.*!!s) { $cut = 1 }' dirt-math.txt
```

or (slightly more readable):

```
perl -pe '
    s!<math>.*?</math>!!g;
    if ($cut) {
        if (s!^.*?</math>!!) { $cut = 0 }
        else { $_ = "" }
    }
    if (!$cut && s!<math>.*!!s) { $cut = 1 }
' dirt-math.txt
```

This is effectively a little state machine.

`$cut` records whether we're in an unclosed `<math>` tag (and so need to cut out input). If so, we check whether we were able to find/remove `</math>`. If so, we're done cutting (we found a closing `</math>` tag); otherwise we overwrite the "current line" with the empty string (`$_ = ""`; this is the actual cutting part).

If, after this, we're not cutting (we're not using `else` to handle the case where `... </math> not math text <math>` appears on a single line), we try to remove `<math>...` from the input. If so, we've just seen an opening `<math>` tag and need to start cutting.

Comment: @Chameleon ... how big are your HTML files?!

Comment: Whole Wikipedia in Polish - it is about 1Gb packed so I can predict that is about 100 Gb.

Comment: @Chameleon Wow. OK, that makes sense, then. Does the second version work better?

Comment: I will start test soon. I trying to clear Wikipedia text to generate some ngrams for machine learning.

Comment: `$bzcat plwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 | wc -c` == 6 419 865 906 bytes

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done using `..` flip-flop(not range) operator without taking the whole file in memory and removing `<math>` from the starting point like:

```
perl -wlne 'unless(((/.*<math>/../<\/math>/)||0) > 1){s/<math>//;print}' your-file
```

Comment: Nice idea I will check this.

Comment: Failed on different file.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite the one-liner but it does what you're looking for. As always there are many ways of doing this. But here I am using '|' as the records separator and ':' as the field separator. That allows me to iterate over the fields in a record that contains math and only print the fields that don't contain `<math></math>`.

```
BEGIN {RS="|";FS=":";ORS=""}

/math/ {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i ~ /math/) {print ":\n"}
        else {print $i}
    }
    print "|";next;
}

/^\}/ {
    print "}";
    next;
}

{
    print $0"|"
}

END {print "\n"}
```

Comment: Do you assume that `: <math>` occurs always it can be also `+++ <math>`?

Comment: @Chameleon I assume that between `:` and `:` or `:` and `|` if there is math then the whole field is ignored so `: +++ <math> ... </math>:` will become `::`