# How to cut html tag with content from huge multiline file with perl, sed or awk (tags in same and different lines all is mixed)?

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

I trying to clear file from `<math>.*?</math>`. It is easy to do it in one line but how to do it with multiline? Where in one line can be more tags or less?

I prepare some test text for Wikipedia to show problem:

```
: <math>A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
   a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \dots \\
   a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \dots \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}
</math> oraz <math>B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
   b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} & \dots \\
   b_{2,1} & b_{2,2} & \dots \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
   B_1 \\
   B_2 \\
   \vdots
\end{bmatrix}
</math>,
```

We discuss problem on Stackoverflow and receive such good solution but not working if line contains overlapping tags like `</math> oraz <math>` it is correct since we have pair but it not works.

I am not expert in awk, sed, perl - only know very well regex.

Perl suggestion (not working on this example):

```
cat dirt-math-2.txt | perl -wlne '
unless(((/.*<math>/../<\/math>/)||0) > 1){s/<math>//;print}
' | less
```

Awk suggestion (not working on this example):

```
cat dirt-math-2.txt | awk '
sub(/<math>.*/, "") {print; cut=1}
/<\/math>/          {cut=0; next}
!cut' | less
```

File to parse is whole Wikipedia in Polish language so it is need be parsed without loading 6Gb into memory. Thank you in advance for any suggestion. I asked some similar question before but it is not the same.

Comment: Already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/a/33052571/1848654.

Comment: @melpomene Do you test it over test data from this question. It now works on 6Gb Mediawiki files where is not possible to load whole file and not allowed. I tested you answer it is good for small files. `-0777` lead to `Out of memory!`.

Comment: BTW I will be not asking again similar question.

Comment: Did you ignore the second part of my answer? I mean the one that doesn't use `-0777`.

Comment: I will try it again maybe second works but I think I was checked. You can test in on this ... - `wget http://dumps.wikimedia.org/plwiki/latest/plwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2` and `bzip2 -c -d plwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 | perl 'something'` I will test on it.

Comment: @melpomene I tested 2nd `perl -pe 's!<math>.*?</math>!!s; if ($cut) { if (s!^.*?</math>!!) { $cut = 0 } else { $_ = "" } } if (!$cut && s!<math>.*!!s) { $cut = 1 }' dirt-math.txt` it works nice on small files. I will try on huge file.

Comment: @melpomene I need to optimize it since it is need to remove many tags together like `<code>`, `<math>`, ... - now it is not big problem since 8 cores will allow many redundant pipes. You script can be the best in perfomace but I need to check it - code looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Perl solution. It works by accumulating lines from the file into a buffer `$text` and then removing all `<math>...</math>` pairs. If the resulting buffer has no opening `<math>` tag then it is printed and emptied. That way, text from the file will only be stored in memory until it has no unpaired `<math>` tags, and normally it will contain only a single line of input

The program expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line. It has been tested against your sample data in this and your previous questions, and works fine

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text;

while ( <> ) {

    $text .= $_;

    $text =~ s/<math>.*?<\/math>//sg;

    if ( $text !~ /<math>/ ) {
        print $text;
        $text = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: I will test it since it looks better at second look! I forget accumulator reset.

Comment: I tested it is great script - not understand last condition but it works (I think it check if nothing more to replace). I will check it on huge data now - some tags can be missed in 1M or articles - maybe if bullet proof.

Comment: @Chameleon: The `if` condition tests whether the `$text` buffer contains an unmatched `<math>` tag (all matched pairs have been removed by the preceding substitution. I don't understand why you tried to edit my solution to use double wuotes instead of single quotes -- it is hardly an improvement!

Answer (score 1):

A way with sed:

```
sed -r ':a;/<math>/{:b;s!<math>([^<]|<[^/]|</[^m]|</m[^a]|</ma[^t]|</mat[^h]|</math[^>])*</math>!!g;ta;N;bb;}' file
```

details:

```php
:a;  # defines the label "a"
/<math>/ {  # condition: if the pattern space contains "<math>"
    :b;  # defines the label "b"
    # try to replace (the ugly alternation "emulate" a non greedy quantifier) 
    s!<math>([^<]|<[^/]|</[^m]|</m[^a]|</ma[^t]|</mat[^h]|</math[^>])*</math>!!g;
    ta; # if something is replaced go to label "a"
    N;  # else append the next line to the pattern space
    bb; # and go to label "b"
}
```

Comment: Black magic for me but I will test it soon.

Comment: @Chameleon: as you can see here (http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html), sed has other features than the simple replacement.

Comment: I only learned basic of sed - need to learn more - it hard since it is very old syntax (from times when we use assemblers and it was o.k.) but I learned many computer languages so it can be more easy for me. Thank you for advanced hint!

Comment: @Chameleon: that is why I used the `-r` option, to preserve your eyes.

Comment: It looks that `-r` will allow futher progress with sed thank you.

Comment: `-r` only allows the ERE (Extended Regular Expression) syntax instead of the BRE (Basic Regular Expression) syntax, the syntax by default for regex patterns. It's useful here to avoid escape parenthesis and to have the alternation operator `|` available.